# Creating a custom database for kraken2 using NCBI and SILVA fasta files

Tags: database, ubuntu

Currently im working on a project where I need to use a metagenomic identifier. I chose to use kraken2. Im encountering some problems using kraken2 and making a custom database.

When I try to make a custom database with the following line:

```
kraken2-build --build --db custom_database /home/database/arb-silva.de_2024-03-06_id1308990_tax_silva_trunc.fasta
```

But I get the following error, no matter what I try:

```
Extra arguments on command line.
Usage: kraken2-build [task option] [options]

Task options (exactly one must be selected):
  --download-taxonomy        Download NCBI taxonomic information
  --download-library TYPE    Download partial library
                             (TYPE = one of "archaea", "bacteria", "plasmid",
                             "viral", "human", "fungi", "plant", "protozoa",
                             "nr", "nt", "UniVec", "UniVec_Core")
  --special TYPE             Download and build a special database
                             (TYPE = one of "greengenes", "silva", "rdp")
  --add-to-library FILE      Add FILE to library
  --build                    Create DB from library
                             (requires taxonomy d/l'ed and at least one file
                             in library)
  --clean                    Remove unneeded files from a built database
  --standard                 Download and build default database
  --help                     Print this message
  --version                  Print version information

Options:
  --db NAME                  Kraken 2 DB name (mandatory except for
                             --help/--version)
  --threads #                Number of threads (def: 1)
  --kmer-len NUM             K-mer length in bp/aa (build task only;
                             def: 35 nt, 15 aa)
  --minimizer-len NUM        Minimizer length in bp/aa (build task only;
                             def: 31 nt, 12 aa)
  --minimizer-spaces NUM     Number of characters in minimizer that are
                             ignored in comparisons (build task only;
                             def: 7 nt, 0 aa)
  --protein                  Build a protein database for translated search
  --no-masking               Used with --standard/--download-library/
                             --add-to-library to avoid masking low-complexity
                             sequences prior to building; masking requires
                             dustmasker or segmasker to be installed in PATH,
                             which some users might not have.
  --max-db-size NUM          Maximum number of bytes for Kraken 2 hash table;
                             if the estimator determines more would normally be
                             needed, the reference library will be downsampled
                             to fit. (Used with --build/--standard/--special)
  --use-ftp                  Use FTP for downloading instead of RSYNC; used with
                             --download-library/--download-taxonomy/--standard.
  --skip-maps                Avoids downloading accession number to taxid maps,
                             used with --download-taxonomy.
  --load-factor FRAC         Proportion of the hash table to be populated
                             (build task only; def: 0.7, must be
                             between 0 and 1).
  --fast-build               Do not require database to be deterministically
                             built when using multiple threads.  This is faster,
                             but does introduce variability in minimizer/LCA
                             pairs.  Used with --build and --standard options.
```

Does anybody have any idea about this?
I also tried it with a NCBI .fasta file, but still didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands:

1. Install taxonomy

```bash
kraken2-build --download-taxonomy --db custom_database
```

2. Add sequence to your database’s genomic library

```bash
kraken2-build --add-to-library /home/database/arb-silva.de_2024-03-06_id1308990_tax_silva_trunc.fasta --db custom_database
```

3. Once your library is finalized, you need to build the database

```bash
kraken2-build --build --db custom_database
```

Source url https://github.com/DerrickWood/kraken2/tree/master/docs